# Sudoku draw the 3*3 square using TabIndex

Tags: c#, sudoku

We are currently having a homework i am struggling with.
Teacher gave us the task to make sudoku-like WFA app made of textboxes.
I already made a rows and colummns highlighed, but I need to highlight the sub-squares as well.
Here's my code:

```
TextBox box = (TextBox)sender; 
        id = box.TabIndex;
        row = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(id / 9) * 9);
        min = row - 8;
        col = Convert.ToInt32((id % 9));
        if (col == 0) col = 9;
        col = col + 72;
        tb_clear();         // function to un-highlight the clicked tb
        foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls)
        {
            if (tb.TabIndex == row)
            {
                tb.BackColor = Color.PowderBlue;
                if (row != min) row--;
            }

            if (tb.TabIndex == col)
            {
                tb.BackColor = Color.PowderBlue;
                col -= 9;
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is how it looks in form:

[image: image-before]

and this is how I want it to look:

[image: image-after]

Thanks, fusionekk.

Comment: So what's your question? A list of things you want isn't a question.  Ask a *specific* question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I forget about it. I just need to know a way, how to highlight the square.

Comment: You could make two routines.  One to highlight rows/columns.  One to highlight the current square.    Then call the first routine, followed by the second.

Comment: Can you describe how to identify all of the squares that need to be highlighted? Can you then translate that description into code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following table:

[image: Table]

Now lets assume that `i` will be our row index and `j` will be our column index. So, position `i = 3` and `j = 5` will be

[image: Highlited]

Now take a better look at our table: it is divided in sectors of 3x3 squares and it has six rows and six columns.

If we divide the row or column index by three, we'd get a number between 0 and 2 (because our max `i` or `j` is 6 - in your case it is between 0 and 3, because your index goes up to 9).

In the following image you can take a better look at how this values change

[image]

So maybe what you could do is get the index of the row (`i`) and column (`j`) of the `SelectedItem` and divide them by 3.

## Some examples:

**`i` = 1 & `j` = 3:**

- i / 3 <= 1, which leaves us with the top side of the table;
- j / 3 <= 1, which leaves us with the left side of the table;
- combine both results and you'll have the **top-left** side of the table

**`i` = 4 & `j` = 4:**

- 1 < i / 3 <= 2, which leaves us with the bottom side of the table;
- 1 < j / 3 <= 2, which leaves us with the right side of the table;
- combine both results and you'll have the **bottom-right** side of the table

Answer (score 2):

You could split your sudoku into 3x3 quares and assign each textbox or each index tuple of (rowindex, columnindx) to one of them manually before running your highlighting code. Then highlight all textboxes that are in the same square.

Or you could try to figure out a mathematical property, that all index tuples of any given square have in common and highlight all textboxes that share that property.